# How do you build and run a dotnet application on Linux created with Visual Studio 2017 on Windows?

Tags: linux, .net-core, visual-studio-2017

Since Visual Studio 2017 and the latest dotnet Core do not use projects.json, how can I make everything run on Linux?  Do I need to go back down to VS 2015?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Heck no. Install the latest dotnet on Linux, copy the tree over, and run dotnet build.

Comment: Am I correct that you mean copy the source over and use build?  Not the already compiled project.

Comment: This is correct. The latest VS on Windows produces projects compatible with the latest dotnet CLI on Linux/Mac, and vice versa.

Comment: @johnny: There's a way to make binaries run. I just haven't worked it all out yet.